# Do I need to check the format of binding arguments of a better-sqlite3 command

Tags: sql, security, sqlite, better-sqlite3

Take a look at this code which uses `better-sqlite3`:

```
router.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
    var rc = req.params('code')
    var code_entry = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM pending_registrations WHERE code = ?').get(rc)
    if (code_entry === undefined) {
        res.send({ success: false })
    }
```

Do I need to verify that `code` parameter of the post query is correctly formatted? Is it possible for this code to malfunction if input is bad?

Comment: Worst that will happen is that it won't match anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL parameters do not need formatting; they are not inserted into the query text, but passed directly to the database. (This is the only practical way to handle blobs, which can literally contain anything.)